# How can I increase the array size with malloc?

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I tried to make a function that add a member in an array of struct and then increase its dimension.

```
void addMember(id **list, size_t *size)
{
    (*size)++;
    *list = *size == 1 ? malloc(sizeof(id)) : realloc(*list, *size * sizeof(id));

    if(!list) {
        printf("Dynamic allocation failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    list[*size-1]->name = malloc (30 * sizeof(char));
    list[*size-1]->surname = malloc (30 * sizeof(char));
    list[*size-1]->number = malloc (15 * sizeof(char));

    if(!list[*size-1]->name || !list[*size-1]->surname || !list[*size-1]->number) {
        printf("Dynamic allocation failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Name: ");
    fgets(list[*size-1]->name, 30, stdin);
    list[*size-1]->name[strcspn(list[*size-1]->name, "\n")] = 0;
    list[*size-1]->name = realloc (list[*size-1]->name, strlen(list[*size-1]->name) + 1 * sizeof(char));

    if(strcmp(list[*size-1]->name, "") == 0) {
        printf("You did not enter the name. Try again.\n");
        free(list[*size-1]->name);
        (*size)--;
        *list = realloc(*list, *size * sizeof(id));
        return;
    }

    printf("Surname: ");
    fgets(list[*size-1]->surname, 30, stdin);
    surname[*size-1]->surname[strcspn(list[*size-1]->surname, "\n")] = 0;
    surname[*size-1]->surname = realloc (list[*size-1]->surname, strlen(list[*size-1]->surname) + 1 * sizeof(char));

    if(strcmp(list[*size-1]->surname, "") == 0) {
        printf("You did not enter the surname. Try again.\n");
        free(list[*size-1]->surname);
        (*size)--;
        *list = realloc(*list, *size * sizeof(id));
        return;
    }

    printf("Number: ");
    fgets(list[*size-1]->number, 15, stdin);
    list[*size-1]->number[strcspn(list[*size-1]->number, "\n")] = 0;
    list[*size-1]->number = realloc (list[*size-1]->number, strlen(list[*size-1]->number) + 1 * sizeof(char));

    if(strcmp(list[*size-1]->number, "") == 0) {
        printf("You did not enter the number. Try again.\n");
        free(list[*size-1]->number);
        (*size)--;
        *list = realloc(*list, *size * sizeof(id));
        return;
    }
}
```

However I ran into a problem when I try to add the second member to the array. In fact, during the second call, the program returns me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error here: `list[*size-1]->name = malloc (30 * sizeof(char));`. On the contrary, I can enter the first array member without any problem. How can I solve that? The struct is:

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    char *surname;
    char *number;
} id;
```

## EDIT:

This is the main file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "functions.h"

int main()
{
    id *list = NULL;
    size_t i, size = 0;
    int choice;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    
    do {
        printf("Enter '1' to display all members, enter '2' to add a new member, enter '3' to exit: ");
        scanf("%d%*c", &choice);
        putchar('\n');
        
        switch(choice) {
            case 1:
                if(size == 0)
                    printf("There's no members.\n");
                else
                    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
                printf("%s %s\n", list[i].name, list[i].surname);
                break;
                
            case 2:
                if(size < 30)
                    addMember(&list, &size);
                break;
        }
        
        printf("Press start.");
        getchar(); putchar('\n');
        
    } while(choice != 3);
    
    free(list);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a `main` function that calls `addMember` as necessary to reproduce the problem and show the input you used.

Comment: @link23 Use realloc for this purpose.

Comment: You can `realloc` the array or add a pointer to `id` into the structure and forget about the array. The latter is know as linked list.

Comment: @Bodo I added the main file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list` is a pointer to an array of `id` so it should be: `(*list)[*size-1].name`, etc. You could save some trouble and create some temp vars to use in the function. Use those throughout the function then assign those back at the end of the function.

Example:

```
void addMember(id **list_original, size_t *size_original)
{
    id *list = *list_original;
    int size = *size_original;
 
    size++;
    list = size == 1 ? malloc(sizeof(id)) : realloc(list, size * sizeof(id));
    if (!list) return; // Nothing to do as original values are untouched
    list[size-1].name = malloc (30 * sizeof(char));
    // etc...

    *list_original = list;
    *size_original = size;
}
```

Another option is to wrap the values in a struct and pass a pointer to that to the function:

```
typedef struct {
    id *list;
    size_t size;
} list_data;
void addMember(list_data *list)
{
   // If you pass NULL to realloc it acts like malloc
   id *tmp = realloc(list->list, (list->size + 1) * sizeof(id));
   if (!tmp) return;
   list->list = tmp;
   list->list[list->size].name = malloc(30);
   // etc...
   list->size += 1;
}
int main()
{
    list_data list = {NULL, 0};
    addMember(&list);
    // ....
}
```

Side note: it is bad practice to use the pointer passed to `realloc` in the result:

```
list = realloc(list, size * sizeof(id));
```

The reason is that if `realloc` fails, the original memory is lost. Use a temp var.

```
id *temp_list = realloc(list, size * sizeof(id));
if (temp_list) {
    list = temp_list;
    // Continue
}
```

Comment: I tried with the second option but I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the first `id *tmp = realloc(list->list, (list->size + 1) * sizeof(id))`

Comment: @link23 Perhaps you missed something. Here's a working example: https://ideone.com/fMEVxC

Comment: Thanks, my program works. Now I am trying to implement the variable tmp but I encounter some error and I think the program can be improved. For example, if I wrote Miles Davis and John Coltrane, the program prints two times John Coltrane.
https://ideone.com/rs9yux

Comment: @link23 The issue with your code is that `tmp` is an array so you need to access it with `tmp[list->size].name` etc. Here's another example with the code cleaned up a bit. https://ideone.com/bBLBEy

Comment: In this way the user can enter empty string. I solved this problem with `if(strcmp(buffer, "\n"))` instead of `if(buffer[0])`. Anyway, thank you again :)

Comment: @link23 Ok. Glad to help. The line `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;` should have been before `if (buffer[0])`. Then it would have worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226626/discussion-between-link23-and-johnny-mopp).